# Tkinter: Determine Widget Position relative to Root Window

Tags: python, tkinter

The tkinter MouseWheel event can only be bound to the root window. Thus the event position is also relative to the root position. 
For a canvas zooming operation, I would like to get the MouseWheel-event with information about the cursor-position within the canvas. To calculate this I thought I would simply subtract the position of the canvas within the root window. Problem now is, that I can not find out the canvas position in the window.

I tried: 
can.grid_bbox  --> (0,0,0,0)  ?
can.grid_info
can.grid_location
cget("offset")
pointerx

and some others I can't remember. Somehow I keep on missing it could someone give me a hint?

---edit---
To get the position of the mouseWheel event relative to the canvas, this approach seems to work:

```
def on_mouse_wheel(self, event):
    xCan = event.x_root - self.can.winfo_rootx()
    yCan = event.y_root - self.can.winfo_rooty()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [winfo_x and winfo_y](http://web.archive.org/web/20131521010600/http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/x9548-window-related-information.htm) methods to get the x/y position relative to the parent.

Comment: It worked by looping through all enclosing frames up to the root (via x.master until .master==None). I did not like this approach and finally I found another solution (see edit above). Thanks though for getting me on the right track again.