# How place toplevel window?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I found problem which I can't solve. Tried to google problem and closest is here [Tkinter: Determine Widget Position relative to Root Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860491/tkinter-determine-widget-position-relative-to-root-window) and here [Window Related Information](https://web.archive.org/web/20070328225104id_/http://www.pythonware.com:80/library/tkinter/introduction/x9548-window-related-information.htm) but I don't understand. Can you help me understand? As can you see I wrote tkinter GUI. In main root window there are two frames. In top are two buttons which launches two toplevel windows. I need to place toplevel windows inside bottom frame. And if I will move main window toplevel will be 'glued' to it. How do this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button

def toplevel1():
    top=tk.Toplevel()
    top.geometry("600x300+300+270")
    top.overrideredirect(1)

def toplevel2():
    top=tk.Toplevel()
    top.geometry("600x300+300+270")
    top.overrideredirect(1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400+300+150")

tf = tk.Frame(root, height='100' ,width='600').pack(side='top')
bf = tk.Frame(root, height='300', width='600').pack(side='bottom')

b1 = tk.Button(tf, bg='yellow', text='Button1', command=toplevel1).place(height='100' ,width='300', x='0', y='0')
b2 = tk.Button(tf, bg='black', fg='white', text='Button2', command=toplevel2).place(height='100' ,width='300', x='300', y='0')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want. Toplevel windows are independent. You can't put them in frames.

If you want them to move when you move the main window, you can put a binding on the `<Configure>` event of the main window to catch when it moves. You can then write some code to move the other toplevel windows using their `geometry` method.

Comment: I think there is one 'cheat'. Borderless windows cant be moved so i need to make borderless main window and add quit button. Is this good idea?